# db query in c# windows service - execution fails silently

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

** warning - c# newbie **

I'm trying to cobble together a Windows service that queries an MSSQL database.

I've created the basic service and confirmed that it can write to the event log.

I've added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model and generated classes from my Database metadata.

Inside my Service's periodic OnTimer method,  I have the following code:

```
    public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        // TODO: Insert monitoring activities here.
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Monitoring the System 1", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);

        using (var db = new LcsCDREntities())
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("about to query", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);

            var query = from c in db.ConferenceSessionDetailsViews
                        orderby c.SessionIdSeq
                        select c;

            eventLog1.WriteEntry("there are " + query.Count().ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);

            foreach (var item in query)
            {

                eventLog1.WriteEntry("Conference data: " + item.SessionIdTime.ToString(),     EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);
            } 
        }

    }
```

In the event log, I only ever see "Monitoring the System 1" and "about to query".  I never see "there are "... or "Conference data".
I can't run my code in the debugger because it's a Windows Service, I'm relying on Event Log statements to determine where execution stops.  I don't see any errors or exceptions in the Event Log, it just seems as though execution stops at or before the query.

Please could anyone could suggest:
1. why I never see the log statements after "about to query"
2. how else I might observe/debug the execution of this process

Comment: Little help, here is a good tutorial on running Windows Service as Console application. It will save you some time. http://einaregilsson.com/run-windows-service-as-a-console-program/

Comment: additional note: I have checked the MSSQL server logs but not seen any errors there

Comment: Related to concrete problem, atop of my head it can be that service cannot access the database. You can wrap it up in try/catch.

Comment: Check in MSSQL server logs, if connection is opened at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. You never see any further entries because some database-specific exception occurs that is not being caught by your code. The exact error will have to be determined through the answer to #2.
2. The way to determine what is happening is to wrap the entire method in a try/catch block and log the exception message (and stack trace for production purposes) into the event log. If you are debugging, you can set a breakpoint on in the catch statement to see exactly what is happening.

   ```
   public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
   {
       try
       {
           // TODO: Insert monitoring activities here.
           eventLog1.WriteEntry("Monitoring the System 1", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);

           using (var db = new LcsCDREntities())
           {
               eventLog1.WriteEntry("about to query", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);

               var query = from c in db.ConferenceSessionDetailsViews
                           orderby c.SessionIdSeq
                           select c;

               eventLog1.WriteEntry("there are " + query.Count().ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);

               foreach (var item in query)
               {

                   eventLog1.WriteEntry("Conference data: " + item.SessionIdTime.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           eventLog1.WriteEntry("Exception: " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
       }
   }
   ```

I would strongly suggest taking a look at Microsoft's [Exception Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440728%28v=pandp.60%29.aspx). Not only do they have excellent guidance on exception handling best practices, they also include fully-baked functionality that you can roll right into your application.

We have been using this block since it was first introduced (something like 10 years ago)  and it has saved us an enormous amount of time and substantially improved the quality of our applications.

Comment: I learned a lot from this question/answer.  My bad assumption was that exceptions thrown in the Service code would automatically end up somewhere e.g Event Log;  Thanks also to @TheLittleHawk